# How to trigger JavaScript function after Table creation

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have a form where after the button click a set of prediction results are generated to the table. below is the code of the form

```
            <form id="target" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div name ="up" class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <button name="upload" class="btn" onchange= "predictResult()">Upload Comments</button>
                <input type="file" id="file" value="go" name="file" onchange="$('#target').submit();"/>
              </div>
            </form>
```

This is the table

```
        <table  class="dataframe data" id="tbb" >
            <tr>
                {% for col in titles %}
                <th>{{col}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% for row in tables %}
            <tr>
                {% for col, row_ in zip(titles, row) %}
                  {% if col == link_column %}
                    <td id="Com1">
                        {{ row_ }}
                    
                    </td>
                  {% elif col == link_column2 %}
                    <td id="Pred">
                        {{ row_ }}
                    
                    </td>
                  {% else %}
                    <td>{{row_}}</td>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        
          </table>
```

I am trying to trigger an alert message after the table is created using javascript. the function is that below

```
function predictResult(){
  alert("sucess");
}
```

when I try to run the program this function is not triggered, can anyone tell me how to triggered the function after creating the table

Comment: How are the prediction results generated? Does that involve an Ajax request or a regular form submission?

Comment: In your case you just need to actually call the function. You've defined it, but now just have a line at the bottom of your table in script: `predictResult()`. That said, it's better if you run scripts like that after page load, as in `window.onload = function (predictResult();}`

Comment: Buttons do not change. So predictResult will not be triggered. Also `<input type="file" id="file" value="go" name="file" onchange="$('#target').submit();"/>` can be written simpler as `<input type="file" id="file" value="go" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>` but realise any submit handlers will not be executed
` Since you submit the form, any script on the page will be ignored at submit time unless you use AJAX